# Obtaining MYSQL results without repeating duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a hard time obtaining results from my database. I have a table that lists Cars by Brands, another table lists Cars by models, and another one assigns which model belongs to which brand.

Here are my tables:

Brands:

```
+--------------+----------------+
| car_brand_id | car_brand_name |
+--------------+----------------+
| 1            | acura          |
+--------------+----------------+
| 2            | honda          |
+--------------+----------------+
| 3            | toyota         |
+--------------+----------------+
| 4            | audi           |
+--------------+----------------+
```

Models:

```
+--------------+----------------+
| car_model_id | car_model_name |
+--------------+----------------+
| 1            | sienna         |
+--------------+----------------+
| 2            | corolla        |
+--------------+----------------+
| 3            | mdx            |
+--------------+----------------+
| 4            | accord         |
+--------------+----------------+
| 5            | a4             |
+--------------+----------------+
```

Assignments:

```
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| assign_id | car_brand_fk_id | car_model_fk_id |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1         | 1               | 3               |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 2         | 2               | 4               |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 3         | 3               | 1               |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 4         | 3               | 2               |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 5         | 4               | 5               |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Currently I'm doing the following:

```
SELECT brands.car_brand_id, brands.car_brand_name, models.car_model_name
FROM brands
LEFT JOIN assignments ON assignments.car_brand_fk_id=brands.car_brand_id 
LEFT JOIN models ON models.car_model_id=assignments.car_model_fk_id
ORDER BY brands.car_brand_name
```

and these are my results:

```
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
| car_brand_id | car_brand_name | car_model_name |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
| 1            | acura          | mdx            |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
| 2            | honda          | accord         |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
| 3            | toyota         | sienna         |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
| 3            | toyota         | corolla        |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
| 4            | audi           | a4             |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
```

As you can see some of them are being repeated(Toyota). What I would like is the following:

```
+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
| car_brand_id | car_brand_name | car_model_name  |
+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
| 1            | acura          | mdx             |
+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
| 2            | honda          | accord          |
+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
| 3            | toyota         | sienna, corolla |
+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
| 4            | audi           | a4              |
+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please explain the downvote so that I can fix my question

Comment: It looks like the perfect job for function [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: thanks for the answers guys. I will run some tests and try them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by grouping and usign [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT brands.car_brand_id, brands.car_brand_name, group_concat(models.car_model_name separator ', ')
FROM brands
LEFT JOIN assignments ON assignments.car_brand_fk_id=brands.car_brand_id 
LEFT JOIN models ON models.car_model_id=assignments.car_model_fk_id
GROUP BY brands.car_brand_name
ORDER BY brands.car_brand_name
```

Comment: This seems to be working. I have a question though. Why do I need both GROUP BY and ORDER BY?

Comment: `Group by` is required. I just left `order by` as in your question (if you don't need the order drop it).

Answer (score 1):

Try using group by and group_concat function like:

```
SELECT brands.car_brand_id, brands.car_brand_name, GROUP_CONCAT(models.car_model_name) AS car_model_name
FROM brands
LEFT JOIN assignments ON assignments.car_brand_fk_id=brands.car_brand_id 
LEFT JOIN models ON models.car_model_id=assignments.car_model_fk_id
GROUP BY brands.car_brand_id, brands.car_brand_name
ORDER BY brands.car_brand_name
```

Comment: This seems to be working. I have a question though. Why do I need both GROUP BY and ORDER BY?

Comment: Group by because you need to group all of your records by id and name, so you could get unique id and name while order by since you want to show your result in ascending order by name.

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT brands.car_brand_id, brands.car_brand_name, GROUP_CONCAT(models.car_model_name)
FROM brands
LEFT JOIN assignments ON assignments.car_brand_fk_id=brands.car_brand_id 
LEFT JOIN models ON models.car_model_id=assignments.car_model_fk_id
GROUP BY models.car_model_name
ORDER BY brands.car_brand_name
```

Comment: This seems to be working. I have a question though. Why do I need both GROUP BY and ORDER BY?

Comment: @CodeGodie You don't, `ORDER BY` is optional.

Comment: @CodeGodie `GROUP BY` is the key of what makes it work.

Answer (score -1):

YOU CAN USE...

```
select distinct(COLUMN NAME,COLUMN NAME,COLUMN NAME);
```